# How can I use xsl stylesheet parameters to set a node name in XPATH expression?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XPATH expression:

```
select="catalog/product/$category_name = $category_value"
```

In the given example $category_name and $category_value are the XSL parameters that I receive from my servlet and I want to use them in XSL to filter the XML result based on category and its value.However, for some reason when,say, $category_name parameter equals 'price' attribute of the 'product' parent node and $category_value equals 40, the given expression does not return any result at all! Logically, the expression should be transformed to something like select="catalog/product/price = 40"....I guess there is some problem with specifying the node name which is the category in my case. Can anyone suggest the way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You probably want**:

```
catalog/product/*[name()=$category_name] [. = $category_value]
```

Answer (score 0):

For variable xpath expressions, use dynamic xpath. See [Is it possible to use a Dynamic xPath expression in a xslt style sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551526/is-it-possible-to-use-a-dynamic-xpath-expression-in-a-xslt-style-sheet)