# Process XML using a dynamic list of columns in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I'm new to XSLT and I'm wondering if it is possible to create a flexible XSLT template for processing any XML into CSV, where all I would need to do is change a variable in XSLT containing a separated list of XPath to include in the output?  I need to use vanilla XSLT 1.0 with now external libraries.  Something like the following, is this possible?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="outputlist" select="/*/CUSTOMER_ID;/*/CUSTOMER_NAME;/*/ADDRESS/POSTCODE" />

<!--Split outputlist variable and use each split string as the template match to output those elements-->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is no dynamic XPath evaluation in XSLT 1.0. So, nice as the idea is to pass in a comma-separated list of different expressions, it won't work. Do you have a chance to work with XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Could you use a two pass method, where XSLT is used to interpret the CSV and generate another XSLT that is actually applied to the XML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a Dynamic xPath expression in a xslt style sheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551526/is-it-possible-to-use-a-dynamic-xpath-expression-in-a-xslt-style-sheet)